# Ho to retrieve data from a separate log file

Tags: javascript, php, html, server

I'm looking to retrieve the contents from a log-file which is located in my server directory, and put it in a javascript variable on my index page (also in the same file directory). (on my admin page you can use a form which runs a php code to upload the lat and lng to a log file) and i could really use some help since i am fairly new to this!

The file location for the following html page is (public_html/index.html)

```
    <!doctype=html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> Example </title>    
    </head>

    <body>
            //I DON'T KNOW IF THIS FORM IS NECESSARY
            <form action="retrieve-from-log.php" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Reload 
            the map" />
            </form>
            //BUT I WANT THE VALUE TO UPDATE ON PAGE LOAD OR SOMETHING


        <script>
            var coordinates = THIS IS WHERE I AM LOST;
            //script for initialising the google map
            function initMap(){

                var inställningar = {
                 zoom:15,
                 center:{THIS IS WHERE I WOULD NEED "coordinates" TO BE},
                }
                //new map
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
            settings);

            //new marker pin
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position:{HERE ASWELL},
             map:map,               
            });
        }
    <script>
</body> 
</html>
```

the log file i want ot access is at (public_html/mylog.log)

```
lat:60.6754, lng:17.14174
```

this is the format of which i would like the variable in index.html to be

and the php file is located in (public_html/retrieve-from-log.php)

```
<?php
$log_file_name = 'mylog.log'; // Change to the log file name
file_get_contents($log_file_name);
$lat = $_GET['lat']; // incoming message
$lng = $_GET['lng']; // incoming message

header('Location:/index.html'); // redirect back to the main site
?>
```

Comment: What exactly do you have a problem with: Reading the log file with PHP, or setting the value of a Javascript variable?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including both your PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: I don't know the code to declare a variable with the contents of another file. I'll try to create the "Minimal Reproducible Example" to clarify

Comment: I think you try to accomplish to much in one go. Try to break the task into more manageable sub-tasks. For instance, first try to read the coordinates from the file you have and get them into a PHP variable. It is not clear to me what exactly will be in the log file and how you want to use it, but if you can solve each sub-tasks first then you can put all your solutions together and solve the bigger task.

Comment: I see what you mean, I'm a bit stressed out haha. But say I'd like to get the coordinates into a variable in php. Is there a quick way of doing it?

Comment: If you can make clear what the content of the file containing the coordinates is, and how you plan to use them, then I can show you.

Comment: "lat:60.6754, lng:17.14174"     This is the only piece of text that is in the .log file. Everytime i use the form to submit the coordinates, it overwrites the current content, which is what I want it to do

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that your 'log file' only ever will contain one line with something like:

`lat:60.6754, lng:17.14174`

With PHP you can read the content of such a file with:

```
<?php

$filename = 'mylog.log';
$content  = file_get_contents($filename);
```

See: [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) in the manual. Notice how this function returns the file content which is stored in a variable.

Now I think you might want to have the latitude and longitude in separate PHP variables. The way to do that is:

```
<?php

$content     = "lat:60.6754, lng:17.14174";
$coordinates = explode(", ", $content);
$latitude    = substr($coordinates[0], 4);
$longitude   = substr($coordinates[1], 4);
```

Now you can use those PHP variables in PHP, for instance to put in Javascript:

```
<script>
   var latitude  = <?php echo $latitude; ?>;
   var longitude = <?php echo $longitude; ?>;
   .... now you can use them in javascript ....
</script>
```

Putting it all together gives:

```
<?php

$filename    = 'mylog.log';
$content     = file_get_contents($filename);
$coordinates = explode(", ", $content);
$latitude    = substr($coordinates[0], 4);
$longitude   = substr($coordinates[1], 4);

?>
<script>
   var latitude  = <?php echo $latitude; ?>;
   var longitude = <?php echo $longitude; ?>;
   .... now you can use them in javascript ....
</script>
```

This you can put in your `index.php` PHP script.

Comment: Can i implement the php-section in my index.html file or do i need to create a seperate .php file for that?

Comment: Step by step. First make a new PHP file and try out this code. Does it do what you want? Do you understand it? And only when that's the case think about integrating it with your other code.

Comment: Alright, i will do that! as i mentioned, I'm fairly new to this, so huge thanks to you for helping me out!

Comment: I got it working and all, and the php will correctly display the submitted coordinates! but now for the final task which is to declair a javascript variable in "index.html" which has the value of the same variables in "retrieve-from-log.php" quickest way?. I hope I'm not bugging you with all my questions.

Comment: @Henkebenk I updated my answer with the code you can put in the `index.php` file. Note the extension is ".php" and not ".html". Simply rename your `index.html` to `index.php`. You need the ".php" extension to make PHP work.

Comment: I must be smart as a rock... I've been using, like you said, html instead of php. Well now the problem is solved and i got everything up and running, You really helped me on this one

Answer (score 0):

the extension is ".php" and not ".html". Simply rename your index.html to index.php. You need the ".php" extension to make PHP work.

Kudos to https://stackoverflow.com/users/3986005/kiko-software